# AADB2C90080: The provided grant has expired. Please re-authenticate and try again

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, msal-angular

We are using azure/msal-angular v2.3 with ADB2C Custom policies having MFA enabled with either Phone or Email method.

Many LIVE users are reporting issues while logging in.
At times they need to do MFA twice (at times thrice) to get into the application.
After digging into the audit logs from b2c and HAR file from the customer we observed below error is being raised in User Journey.

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "AADB2C90080: The provided grant has expired. Please re-authenticate and try again. Current time: 1676016884, Grant issued time: 1675941825, Grant expiration time: 1675951412\r\nCorrelation ID: 6052f247\r\nTimestamp: 2023-02-10 08:14:44Z\r\n"
}
```

As per my understanding msal 2.x automatically handles the token refresh and we don’t need to implement any code for acquiring tokens silently. Don't know why it is expring.

Is it affecting if user keeps the screen idle for long?

Any help to resolve this is appreciated , Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if this can help you but see this post on Github Issues: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/1004#issuecomment-620851414

Comment: My guess is, you need to implement the acquireTokenSilent() method still with the refresh token. See here: https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/classes/_azure_msal_angular.msalservice.html#acquiretokensilent

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that msal 2.x automatically takes care to refresh token. But in few cases when user is inactive for long time or when access token expiry is less than the refresh token default time set.

In that case, `acquireTokenSilent()` method can be used to obtain a new token.To obtain a new access token silently, call the acquireTokenSilent() method of the MsalService with the desired scopes.

**Code:**

```
getToken() {
this.authService.acquireTokenSilent({
  scopes: ['<your-scope>'],
}).then((accessToken: string) => {
  // Use the access token  // console.log('New token:', token);
}).catch((error: any) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

- Check  expiration times of the access and refresh tokens, and refresh  interval set. Adjust these settings using `accessTokenExpirationOffsetInSeconds` property to tell number of seconds/minutes before which refresh token has  to be set.

  ```
   this.authService.init({
    auth: {
      clientId: '<your-client-id>',
      authority: '<your-b2c-tenant>.b2clogin.com/<b2c-tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_<policy-name>',
      redirectUri: '<your-redirect-uri>',
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
      storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
      accessTokenExpirationOffsetInSeconds: 300,
    },
  });
  }
  ```

In this MSAL will try to refresh the access token within 5 minutes ~ 300 seconds before it expires.

- This error or failure can happen if the user takes too long to complete the MFA flow.
- For that ,In custom policy  set the timeout for mutifactor authentication to 5 minutes to give minimum time for user to authenticate.

  ```
  <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="MultiFactorAuthentication">
  <MultiFactorAuthentication>
    <AuthenticationMethods>
      <AuthenticationMethod ReferenceId="phoneFactor" />
      <AuthenticationMethod ReferenceId="emailFactor" />
    </AuthenticationMethods>
    <FailureModes>Deny</FailureModes>
    <Default>false</Default>
    <SendErrorCodesToResponse>false</SendErrorCodesToResponse>
    <Enrollment>Conditional</Enrollment>
    <phoneFactor-Timeout>300</phoneFactor-Timeout>
    <emailFactor-Timeout>300</emailFactor-Timeout>
  </MultiFactorAuthentication>
  ```

[image]

By theses token refresh behavior can be contolled.

**Reference :**

1. [Configure authentication in a sample single-page application by using Azure Active Directory B2C | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-spa-app)
2. [Configure session behavior - Azure Active Directory B2C | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, Can you please also tell me when should I call acquireTokenSilent? What will be the trigger for this?

Comment: Before the user logs in or during Api call , acquireTokenSilent can be triggered

Answer (score 0):

While doing development work on custom B2C policies, we found that this error sometimes appeared.

The way we got around it was clearing the local storage and session storage for the b2c domain and then we did not see this error again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34673287)